# Upgrade Symfony 1_4 Project to Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4

I have a legacy application which uses

- Symfony 1_4
- PHP 5.3
- MySQL 5.6

Client is asking for an upgrade of all the tech stack to the latest.

- Symfony 5
- PHP 8
- MySQL 8

How can I do this upgrade with minimum effort ?
A solution required without re-writing the whole application.

**Upgraded application's security should be major feature**

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Im also in the same situation and starting from a position of having no idea what the best approach is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading from such an old version to the latest version is most likely never going to work.
I suggest rebuilding the application in Symfony 5 manually, it will probably save you a lot time and effort.

You can try to reuse as much business logic as you can.